# Open all files in same folder as active workbook EXCEPT active workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a macro that opens each excel file in the same folder that the workbook containing the macro (I'll call it the master workbook) is in and copies all the data in the first spreadsheet, then pastes them into the master workbook on a new worksheet.  I found some very useful code online that I made a few changes to.  Everything seems to be working fine, except that while this code is opening each file in the folder (in the Do Until loop), it opens itself half way through.

I'd like to be able to avoid this without referencing the master spread sheet's name directly, in case someone renames it.

Is there a simple command that will make skip the remaining code in the loop if it tries to open itself?

Code is below:

```
Sub CombineWSs()
Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim strFilename As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path 
Set wbDst = ThisWorkbook
strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "\*.xls", vbNormal)

If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

Do Until strFilename = ""

        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & "\" & strFilename)
        Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)

        'copy the data
        wbSrc.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
        Selection.Copy

        'create a new worksheet in this master file
        wbDst.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

        'paste the data into master file's new sheet
        wbDst.Sheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

        wbSrc.Close False

    strFilename = Dir()

Loop
wbDst.Worksheets(1).Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it if you do reference the name directly? You don't need to know the workbook's name. I would add something like `If strFilename = activeworkbook.name Then ` and then continue with your `Do While` loop, and place `End If` after `loop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put an `If` block inside our loop

```
Do Until strFilename = ""

   If strFilename <> wbDest.Name Then 'since you already set wbDest = ThisWorkbook

      '... rest of code

   End If

Loop
```

Comment: Can you mix `while` and `until` in loops? Could he do something like `Do Until strFilename = "" and while strfilename <> ThisWorkbook.Name`?

Comment: ASAIK that is not possible, @BruceWayne